# Error when creating AWS Cloudfront self signed urls (java sdk)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to create self signed urls with AWS cloudfront. This is my code:

```
public class SignedUrl {

public void generateSignedUrl(String objectKey) throws IOException {
    // the DNS name of your CloudFront distribution, or a registered alias
    String distributionDomainName = "mydomain";
    // the private key you created in the AWS Management Console
    File cloudFrontPrivateKeyFile = new File(".");
    File[] matchingFiles = cloudFrontPrivateKeyFile.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".pem");
        }
    });
    System.out.println(matchingFiles[0].getCanonicalPath());
    String cloudFrontKeyPairId = "mykey";
    Date expirationDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 1000);
    try {
        String signedUrl = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy(
                SignerUtils.Protocol.https,
                distributionDomainName,
                cloudFrontPrivateKeyFile,
                objectKey,
                cloudFrontKeyPairId,
                expirationDate);

    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I followed an AWS tutorial with these example, created my Cloudfront public and private key, but I am getting an error:

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unsupported file type for private key

Does anybody know how to solve this? I tried to convert to .der file (I read in an old AWS documentation) but still did not work.

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer but `cloudFrontPrivateKeyFile` seems to be a directory and you are finding and printing `matchingfiles[0]` but then not actually using it for anything else.  Why the convolution?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I copied a wrong version of the code. Even if I pass the matchingfiles to a File variable I get an error.